# Smoothness and the eigenvalues of the Hessian

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions, smooth-functions

A continuously differentiable function $f$ is $\beta$-smooth if the gradient is $\beta$-Lipschitz:
$$ || \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)|| \leq \beta ||x-y||, $$
where $\nabla f(\cdot)$ denotes the gradient vector of $f$ at  a given point, $\beta$ is a scalar, and $||\cdot||$ is an $\ell_2$-norm.

In the book *Convex Optimization: Algorithms and Complexity* by *Sebastien Bubeck* it is said that:

> The above Lipschitz condition implies (if the function is twice
>   differentiable) the eigenvalues of the Hessians being smaller than
>   $\beta$.

I cannot see how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $y=x+v$ with $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ being any non-zero vector. Therefore, 
$$
\frac{||\nabla f(x+v)-f(x)||_2}{||v||_2} \leq \beta
$$
As the derivative is a linear approximation, we have 
$$
\nabla f(x+v)=\nabla f(x)+\nabla^2f(x)v+r(v)
$$
Here $\lim_{v \to 0} \frac{r(v)}{||v||_2}=0$. 
Rearranging, taking norms, dividing and the triangle inequality give 
$$
\frac{||\nabla^2f(x)v||_2}{||v||_2} \leq\frac{||\nabla f(x+v)-f(x)||_2}{||v||_2}+ \frac{||r(v)||_2}{||v||^2}\leq \beta+\frac{||r(v)||_2}{||v||^2}
$$
Note that the Hessian is symmetric. Assumingt there exists a $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\nabla^2f(x) v=\lambda v $ and $|\lambda| >\beta$, we can plug in $tv$ for $t\in \mathbb R \setminus \{ 0\}$ in the above inequality and obtain 
$$
|\lambda| \leq \beta+\frac{||r(tv)||_2}{||tv||^2}
$$
Sending $t \to 0$ gives a contraditiction.